# how to get input value inside label have active class

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i want to get input id value from label that have active class and i tried with this but only have undefined alert guys can you please tell me how i can do this thank you.

HTML:

```
 <label class="btn btn-default active">
  <input type="radio" name="activity" id="{$base}p/handler/?handle=privmsg&output=html">
 Msgs</label>
 <label class="btn btn-default">
   <input type="radio" name="activity" id="{$base}p/handler/handle=notify&output=html">
 notify</label>
```

JS:

```
g = $('label[class="btn btn-default active"]').next().attr('id');
    alert(g);
```

Comment: like this `$("label.active").find("input").attr("id")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change this:

```
g = $('label[class="btn btn-default active"]').next().attr('id');
```

to:

```
g = $('.active input[type="radio"]').attr('id');
```

```js
g = $('.active input[type="radio"]').attr('id');
console.log(g);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn btn-default active">
  <input type="radio" name="activity" id="{$base}p/handler/?handle=privmsg&output=html">
   Msgs
</label>
 <label class="btn btn-default">
   <input type="radio" name="activity" id="{$base}p/handler/handle=notify&output=html">
    notify
 </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the selector as below

```
xyz = jQuery('.active input[type="radio"]').attr('id');
alert(xyz);
console.log(xyz);
```